# Best way to port map to multiple entities

Tags: vhdl

If a certain entity needs to be referenced many times in another "top-level" entity, what is the best way to do that?

For instance, given a certain entity `My_Entity` (simplified description here):

```
entity My_Entity is
    port (
        etc ...
    );
end My_Entity;
```

...how would I describe a top-level entity that uses *10* `My_Entity`'s?

```
entity Top_Entity is
    port (
        etc ...
    );
end Top_Entity;

architecture rtl of Top_Entity is
begin
    entity1 : entity work.My_Entity(rtl) port map (
        etc ...
    );

    entity2 : entity work.My_Entity(rtl) port map (
        etc ...
    );

    -- repeat 10 times? or is there a better way?
end rtl;
```

Comment: read up on for..generate

Comment: something explained in every good VHDL book. Even the bad ones mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use a *generate loop*:

```
entity Top_Entity is
    port (
        etc ...
    );
end Top_Entity;

architecture rtl of Top_Entity is
begin

    G: for I in 1 to 10 generate   -- the label "G" is compulsory here
        -- I varies between 1 and 10 here
        -- you can use it to distinguish between instances
        -- eg to connect each to a different element of an array
        entity1 : entity work.My_Entity(rtl) port map (
             etc ...
        );
    end generate;

end rtl;
```